# Trying to make a simple program that gives the day of any given date

Tags: python, datetime

I've got this:

```
from datetime import date
import calendar

curr_date = date.today()
print(calendar.day_name[curr_date.weekday()])
```

but that just tells me what day today is, how can I make it so that I can input a date? I've tried this but I get an error telling me `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'weekday'`

```
from datetime import date
import calendar

curr_date = input()
print(calendar.day_name[curr_date.weekday()])
```

Can someone help me solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try code below:

```py
from dateutil import parser

curr_date = input()
print(parser.parse(curr_date).strftime("%A"))
```

##### Output

```
2022/02/19
Saturday
```

##### Explanation

`parser` has an inner function named `parse` which takes a date time in string and returns `datetime` object. Using `strftime` you can simply change this `datetime` object into string. `%A` is pointing to the `weekday's as the local's full name`. If you are interested to get more data, such as the month name, you can use `%A %B` which returns the name of the day followed by the month full name.

Comment: thanks! i don't have the module called dateutil though, how do i get that?

Comment: @LarsvanMil `pip install python-dateutil`.

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary okay where do i enter that? sorry i'm a complete noob

Comment: @LarsvanMil check [this page](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/#installing-packages)